# From C# to Excel - ConditionalFormat

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have a two cell created in C# which I get by

```
workSheet.Cell("A1");
workSheet.Cell("B1");
```

I am adding conditional format for both of these cells as below:

First case:

```
workSheet.Cell("A1").AddConditionalFormat().IconSet(XLIconSetStyle.ThreeTrafficLights2)
                    .AddValue(XLCFIconSetOperator.EqualOrGreaterThan, 0, XLCFContentType.Number)
                    .AddValue(XLCFIconSetOperator.EqualOrGreaterThan, 20, XLCFContentType.Number)
                    .AddValue(XLCFIconSetOperator.EqualOrGreaterThan, 40, XLCFContentType.Number);
```

Second case

```
workSheet.Cell("B1").AddConditionalFormat().IconSet(XLIconSetStyle.ThreeSigns)
                   .AddValue(XLCFIconSetOperator.EqualOrGreaterThan, 0, XLCFContentType.Number)
                   .AddValue(XLCFIconSetOperator.EqualOrGreaterThan, 75, XLCFContentType.Number)
                   .AddValue(XLCFIconSetOperator.EqualOrGreaterThan, 95, XLCFContentType.Number);
```

The problem is that XLCFIconSetOperator has only to properies
Equal and EqualOrGreaterThan.

It the first case I want "better" sign for lower values e.g:

```
0-19 - green
20-39 - yellow
40 +  -  red
```

In second case I want revert that :

```
0-19 - red
20-39 - yellow
40 +  -  red
```

In above second case is working without any problem. How I can solve it in first case if there is not Less/EqualOrLess property?

Comment: A workarond would be to create an inverted value in the scale `y = max - x` and apply the formating to this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
....AddConditionalFormat().IconSet(XLIconSetStyle.ThreeTrafficLights2, true)....
```

The second parameter is `bool reverseIconOrder`.